# How to dynamically build a form based on TreeBuilder object?

Tags: php, forms, configuration, symfony

I want to define configuration schema for my class and override them with admin choices.
In order to do this I need a form to capture data from admin.

In Symfony `Configuration Component`, the `TreeBuilder` class is responsible for defining configuration schema. and as you know `Form Component` has tree like structure similar to `TreeBuilder`.

How can dynamically make a `Form` object based on `TreeBuilder` instance?

Comment: You can use the `formBuilder` to dynamically build the form based on the `treeBuilder` output right?

Comment: How is it possible in an automatic manner?

Answer (score 1):

Your treebuilder, or a part of it, will have to be iterable. So by letting it represent a form as strict as possible you can use it to easily map the configuration to the builder. It would be easiest to use the `yml` format:

```
form:
    name: 'exampleForm'
    path: 'target_path'
    fields:
        fieldName:
            type: 'TextType'
            attr:
                # some additional options
        otherFieldName:
            type: 'TextType'
            attr:
                # some additional options
```

See the processing section of the config component for more info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#processing-configuration-values

The processed configuration then could be handled with the form factory and would probably look like this:

```
$config = $configuration->processConfiguration($config, FormType::class, null, $config['path']);
$formBuilder = $container->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($config['name');

foreach ($config['fields'] as $field) {
    $formBuilder->add($fieldName, $field['type'], $field['attr']);
}
$form = $formBuilder->createForm();
```